# GCP Logging - read only logs that are not exported to any sink

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Using GCP's Java SDK, I'd like to read only logs that are not configured to be exported to any sink.

When I call `com.google.cloud.logging.Logging.listLogEntries()` I get all of the logs, including logs are exported to sinks I have configured.

Any way to collect only log entries that are not configured to be exported to any sink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `EntryListOption` to get filtered log entries as explained on [this page](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging).

```
  Page<LogEntry> entries = logging.listLogEntries( 
        EntryListOption.filter("logName=projects/" + options.getProjectId() + "/logs/test-log"));
        Iterator<LogEntry> entryIterator = entries.iterateAll().iterator();
        while (entryIterator.hasNext()) {
          System.out.println(entryIterator.next());
        }
```

> Any way to collect only log entries that are not configured to be exported to any sink?

In order to achieve this,

1. you need to get all sinks using [REST api](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.sinks/list) or equivalent [java client](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging/tree/master/proto-google-cloud-logging-v2/src/main/java/com/google/logging/v2)
2. iterate over sinks to get each filter query
3. build a dynamic filter to use with the above `EntryListOption`

Comment: not the most aesthetic of solutions, I would have expected a filter like sink=none or anything that wouldn't require reading all the sinks and constructing a huge (possibly over the filter char size limit),
but it would do for the limited # of sinks I have...

Comment: I agree, having sink=none would be very handy in this case but currently it's not possible query log entries in such a way.